# Plain text parsing using java

Tags: java

I have an output from ssh like below. I want to parse the below output to an hashmap using java. any suggestions can be helpful...

```
Name        : mysql                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.1.61                            Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 4.el6                         Build Date: Fri 22 Jun 2012 05:58:59 AM PDT
Install Date: Tue 13 Nov 2012 02:23:23 AM PST      Build Host: c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org
URL         : http://www.mysql.com
Summary     : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
```

My output should be a hashmap like

**Key           Value**

Name           mysql

Relocations  (not relocatable)

Version        5.1.61

Release         4.el6

Comment: If you above data is like a property file than you can use [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) or else you can read line by line and create a HashMap after splitting the string by the seperator...

Comment: Three questions: (1) There maybe one or two key/value pairs in each line, right? Or may there be even more in a single line? (2) Is the set of keys known/fixed or are the keys arbitrary strings? (3) Are the whitespace characters simple spaces or are there any tab characters involved?

Comment: 1) as of now assume that we have one or two key/value pairs in each line 2) keys fixed 3) white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression should do the trick here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Name        : mysql                        Relocations: (not relocatable)\n");
    sb.append("Version     : 5.1.61                            Vendor: CentOS\n");
    sb.append("Release     : 4.el6                         Build Date: Fri 22 Jun 2012 05:58:59 AM PDT\n");
    sb.append("Install Date: Tue 13 Nov 2012 02:23:23 AM PST      Build Host: c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org\n");
    sb.append("URL         : http://www.mysql.com\n");
    sb.append("Summary     : MySQL client programs and shared libraries\n");

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\r\\n:]+):\\s(.+?)(\\s{2,}|\\r\\n|\\r|\\n|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sb.toString());
    while(m.find()) {
        String key = m.group(1).trim();
        String value = m.group(2);

        System.out.println(key + " = \"" + value + "\"");
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Name = "mysql"
Relocations = "(not relocatable)"
Version = "5.1.61"
Vendor = "CentOS"
Release = "4.el6"
Build Date = "Fri 22 Jun 2012 05:58:59 AM PDT"
Install Date = "Tue 13 Nov 2012 02:23:23 AM PST"
Build Host = "c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org"
URL = "http://www.mysql.com"
Summary = "MySQL client programs and shared libraries"
```

Comment: its nice ... in what scenarios the regex works? can you explain how u created the regex ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex as a starting point:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*): (.*?)(( {2,})|$)
```

First group should capture the key, second group the value. It assumes two things:

1) There are at least two spaces or the end of the line after a value. 
2) There is never two spaces one after another within a value.

(It is important that these assumptions are really true. They are true in your example but you would need to verify that it is always true for your input.)

I tested it against your example above and it seems to work, try: http://regexpal.com/ (You need to enable checkbox "^$ match at line breaks" at the top to make it work)

If that regex is OK, use `Pattern` and `Matcher` from the Java API to build up your hashmap. Ah, and you should `trim()` your matched keys and values to get rid of the extra spaces at end.

Answer (score 0):

try to create some regular expressions. Since many of the items are pretty defined well you can catch the starting and ending points using `String.indexOf()`. Then get the `substring()`, and develop the hashmap.