# Flat file parsing with java

Tags: java, parsing, wmi

I want to parse below wmi output to hashmap as a key value pair using java.Please give me suggestions ..
My WMI Output contains 2 rows with multiple columns, first row is header and second row contains data. I want either regex or any approach to seperate the header with corresponding data as a key value for hashmap.

I am not getting any idea how to proceed...

```
Caption                  Description              IdentifyingNumber  Name                   

Computer System Product  Computer System Product                     HP xw4600 Workstation
```

Parsing output should be like ...

### **Key        =     Value**

Caption    =      Computer System Product

Description = Computer System Product

IdentifyingNumber =

Name = HP xw4600 Workstation

Comment: `I want to parse below wmi output to hashmap as a key value pair using java.` Nice, why don't you just do it? Are you stuck with an error?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528835/plain-text-parsing-using-java)? And why you accepted it then?

Comment: user714965 ... the answer to other question is good and fits to that question. the formate in the previous question is different from this question.we need to use a different regex for this. can you provide some regex for this fomate ?

Comment: @kumar no, but I think you should try to write this regex yourself. If you have difficulties ask a question about that. That way you will get much more from SO, than letting anybody write all your regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the wmi output as a list and now its easy to formate the output.

Answer (score 0):

If your file format is always the same, you can easy use parser:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String[] array = new String[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    ((BufferedReader)in).readLine();
}
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   array[i] = ((BufferedReader)in).readLine();
   if(array[i] == null)
   {
    array[i] = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
   }
}
in.close();
String[] headers = array[0].split(Pattern.quote("\t")); //$NON-NLS-1$
String[] values = array[1].split(Pattern.quote("\t")); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

And then running through both and filling hashmap

Comment: its not splitting ... headers and values length is 1 only.

Comment: Can U see which delimiter is used in these strings when debugging?

Comment: when i try to split using "\\s+" , the header part is working fine. but data part giving weird result

Comment: i dint get u ... the output is coming from wmi. how can i check that ?

Comment: If U suse my code, which characters are used in String objects in "headers" & in "values" as delimiters?

Comment: i am getting empty chars at each location between the strings ... some times 2 empty chars sometimes multple empty chars

Comment: by using this " {2,}" am able to split it. headers length is coming out as 4 but values length is coming out as 3 only. because the identification no is empty. can sombody help me ...

Comment: Sorry, but I usually worked with files with different types of delimiters, but these were at least defined or could be determined. If there is no difference between empty and delimiter, it's gonna be difficult to split correctly...